# Что означает Yii::$app->request->queryParams?

Tags: php, yii2

Gii в контроллерах Yii стандартно генерирует строку `$params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;`

Прошу знающих "Прочитать" этот код. Я понимаю, что переменной `$params` присваивается какое-то значение.

Что это за значение, и почему оно стандартное для всех контроллеров? Больше всего не ясно с `queryParams`.

Answer (score 1):

[`$queryParam`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#$queryParams-detail) - параметры, которые были переданные в адресе GET запроса.

Comment: а чем тогда Yii::$app->request->queryParams отличается от Yii::$app->request->get(); ?

Comment: @Oughtem `get` возвращает значение конкретного параметра по имени.

Comment: get(['param']) возвращает конкретный параметр по имени, а get() возвращает  массив всех параметров. Поэтому и не ясно чем get() в данном случае отличается от $queryParam

Comment: @Oughtem `Yii::$app->request->get()` создан для удобства.  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/0f4e4226773e2e256f10156b579bd7ab79b493c7/framework/web/Request.php#L657